# Search in Action Bar For Different Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I make an application that uses `Navigation Drawer`. There are several fragments in the navigation drawer each drawer fragment has different functionality.

I want to Implement search criteria in Action Bar so is It possible to make a different - different search criteria in different - different fragments ?

e.g. In students' fragment Action Bar search will searches all the students in the list.
In teachers'  fragment Action Bar search will searches all the teachers in the list.

Please give me your suggestion...

Thanks...

Comment: found any solution?